# Помогите с алгоритмом - нужно собрать пазл

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия

Имеется пазл 5 * 5, составленный из квадратов. Каждая сторона квадрата - число. Сторона, которая является краем имеет значение 0. Данные представлены в виде листа:

```
[[0,[10, 18, 2, 0]], [1,[1, 15, 11, 6]] ... [2,[5, 0, 11, 6]], [3,[11, 13, 0, 9]]]
```

Предполагаю, что должна быть рекурсия. Может начать с угла и строить дальше по двум сторонам методом случайного подбора, пока не получится? Но решение выглядит громоздким.

Примерно такой пазл должен получиться (прошу прощения за каракули):
[image]

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: "Но решение выглядит громоздким." - не вижу решения, поэтому не могу судить о его громоздкости.

Comment: Можно и рекурсией, и итерациями получить решение. Удобнее всего, конечно, начинать с угла.
Создаёшь матрицу 5х5, в которую заносишь номера пазл в нужные позиции. Позиции определяешь перебором всех пазл.

Comment: `Предполагаю, что должна быть рекурсия` Таки расскажите, где вы тут видите рекурсию? Как выглядит тривиальная задача, а как рекурсивный спуск?

Comment: Самая сложная, на мой взгляд, часть в решении пазлов - поиск подходящего кусочка. Поэтому, я бы начал(если память не жалко) с построения карты для быстрого получения кусочков, на которых есть x. Дальше, можно идти, например, по спирали(не суть важно, но нулей больше всего, их стоит разместить первыми), забирая из мапы нужные здесь и сейчас кусочки.

Comment: Ветвление с отсечениями? Начинать с угла - фиксированная позиция, потом потихоньку, эдаким треугольником? Хуже всего, что каждый пазл, как я понимаю, можно вертеть на все 4 стороны... Кстати, единственность решения гарантируется?

Comment: @vp_arth Их всего 25 - можно и перебором, вряд ли это будет основным тормозом.